# modify java files using gawk / awk / sed (to swap java function arguments)

Tags: java, sed, awk, gawk

I have a lot of Java files containing statements like this:

```
assertEquals(x, 0);
```

I would like to swap the 2 arguments in every files. How could I do that programmatically?

Comment: are they all exactly like that, or do they have different variable names?

Comment: No need for awk or sed, your IDE will do that for you (it almost certainly supports regular expressions in find/replace)

Comment: John3136: no both arguements can be random
artbristol: I'm in Eclipse maybe?

Answer (score 7):

```
sed 's/assertEquals(\([^,]*\), *\([^)]*\));/assertEquals(\2, \1);/g' <input.file >output.file
```

**Better:**

```
sed 's/assertEquals(\([^,]*\),[ ]\{0,1\}\([^)]*\));/assertEquals(\2, \1);/g' <input.file >output.file
```

**Explanation:**

- `s/"pattern"/"substitution"/g //` s => substitute, g => on whole line
- `\(...\)` catches subpattern. this can be referred to via `\number`. So the logic is `s/assertEquals("pattern1","??whitespace??""pattern2");/assertEquals("pattern2", "pattern1");/g`
- `[ ]\{0,1\}` matches possible space after comma (0 or 1 occurence) - `[ ]?` did not work for me?

Comment: Thanks that's fantastic!
I just don't understand what's inside the `\(...\):` `[^,]*`

Comment: `[^,]` == "anything except comma", `*` == "0 or more of the previous"

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/[(][ ]*\([^,]*\)[ ]*,[ ]*\([^)]*\)[ ]*[)]/ s::(\2,\1):' FILE
```

- eliminate spaces between the arguments
- swaps the arguments of all function calls that have 2 arguments